# the property of the "Stub Object" object does not meet the checkpoint's condition

Tags: javascript, testing, testcomplete

"the property of the "Stub Object" object does not meet the checkpoint's condition" –I got this error, I tried every type of checkpoint.

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    j = 1;
    cellvalue = grid.wValue(i, j);
    grid.ClickCell(i, j);
    //The problem is this checkpoint;
    aqObject.CheckProperty(Aliases.browser.page1921681611258080.panelTabpanelBody.p‌anelGamblerpanel.panelTabpanel.panelForm.panelFormtargetel.panelContainer2.tableD‌​ isplayfield4.panelDisplayfieldInputel, "contentText", cmpEqual, "995");
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted here test script snippet with which you have the problem.

Comment: for(i=0; i<rows;i++)
{
 j=1;
 cellvalue=grid.wValue(i,j);
 grid.ClickCell(i,j);
 //The problem is this checkpoint;
 aqObject.CheckProperty(Aliases.browser.page1921681611258080.panelTabpanelBody.panelGamblerpanel.panelTabpanel.panelForm.panelFormtargetel.panelContainer2.tableDisplayfield4.panelDisplayfieldInputel,"contentText",cmpEqual,"995");
}

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that the object you pass to the CheckProperty method is not found. You can check the object for existence before calling the checkpoint.

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    j = 1;
    cellvalue = grid.wValue(i, j);
    grid.ClickCell(i, j);
    var obj = Aliases.browser.page1921681611258080.panelTabpanelBody.p‌anelGamblerpanel.panelTabpanel.panelForm.panelFormtargetel.panelContainer2.tableD‌​ isplayfield4.panelDisplayfieldInputel;
//The problem is this checkpoint;
    if (false == obj.Exists)
      Log.Error("The object is not found");
    else
      aqObject.CheckProperty(, "contentText", cmpEqual, "995");
}
```